# Is there any Eclipse/Aptana Studio plugin for ChicagoBoss?

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

Hi I'm a newbie  chicago boss developer, Have switched from Django. Can one tell me if there is a ChicagoBoss plugin in Eclipse or in Aptana?

That's the only editor I like for development. I have already installed erlang plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no plugin for ChicagoBoss in Eclipse nor Aptana,
but IntelliJ offers a great support for Erlang.

IntelliJ Community edition:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

The Erlang plugin is constantly evolving:

http://ignatov.github.io/intellij-erlang/

Unfortunately JavaScript support is an Ultimate Edition feature, so you probably want to code javascript in your preferred editor and Erlang in IntelliJ Community Edition...

Comment: I have been using IntelliJ for erlang. but I'm not much cmfortable, its look and feel is not as much cool as eclipse. So I prefer eclipse.

Thanks for the reply.